# Pandas DataFrame do something if a value is string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, numbers

I have a table with a column named 'Amount'. The cell values are mixture of numbers such as 1, 100, and 1000, and strings such as '(1000)' and '(999)' which indicates a negative value. How would I change the strings of negative values to numbers, like -1000 and -999?
I don't know how to apply conditions on panda dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
ws_actual = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=0)


Project Name    Amount
a   1000.53
b   (-100.2)
c   999.83
d   99999.1
e   333.62
f   (-10502.30)
g   (-2036.63)
h   25235
i   69103
j   5923
k   6920
```

Comment: post your sample data and your desired output

Comment: added a sample image

Comment: Post as *text*, not as an image

Comment: How can I save it as text and how to upload here?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the data in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `strip`.  Although in your question, it is ambiguous if the values in parenthesis contain negative symbols or if the parenthesis need to be replaced with a negative symbol.  If it is the latter you will need a regular expression here.

```
df.Amount.astype(str).str.strip('()').astype(float)
```

```
0      1000.53
1      -100.20
2       999.83
3     99999.10
4       333.62
5    -10502.30
6     -2036.63
7     25235.00
8     69103.00
9      5923.00
10     6920.00
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

If you have strings such as `(1000)` that also need to be converted to a negative number:

```
print(df)

  ProjectName  Amount
0           a  (1000)
1           b     100
2           c   (999)
```

```
df.Amount.astype(str).str.replace(r'\(([-\d\.]+)\)', r'-\1').astype(float)
```

```
0   -1000.0
1     100.0
2    -999.0
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I put df.Amount.astype(str).strip('()').replace(',',"").astype(float) since I realized that there is a comma in (). When I run this code, I get an error saying that 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: '271,796.82''. I think I removed comma, but it was obviously not successful. Could you give a solution to this?

Comment: Use `.str.replace` instead of just `.replace`

Comment: Yay!!! It worked with astype(str).str.replace(',',"").str.replace(r'\(([-\d\.]+)\)', r'-\1').astype(float) !!! Thank you !!!